# Converting a morse string into an array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, string, arduino

So as the title states, the purpose of this program is to take in a string of Morse code, for example .-/.-/.-, into an array of characters. I believe I am pretty much there, however I need to be able to set `morsecat` to be empty as I believe why the program doesn't run correctly is because `morsecat` is continually receiving characters and, when it comes to converting what is held within morsecat into a character, it sees that morsecat is far too long and cannot convert it as it does not match any morse character because it contains two or more morse characters instead of one (which is why the do while loop is there as "/" separates each morse character).
I have attached my code but please feel free to overhaul it if you think thats what it needs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has had me stumped for a little while now.

Note: I am aware that when you try to verify the code it gives the error "empty character constant", as I am not aware of how to reset the value of morsecat so that it contains nothing.

Code for the program below:

```
char * ip = ".-/.-/";
char buf[50];
int buflen;

char morse2char (char * m) {
  if (strcmp(m, ".-") == 0) {
    Serial.println("a");
  }
  else  if (strcmp(m, "-...") == 0) {
    Serial.println("b");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "-.-.") == 0) {
    Serial.println("c");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "-..") == 0) {
    Serial.println("d");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, ".") == 0) {
    Serial.println("e");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "..-.") == 0) {
    Serial.println("f");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "--.") == 0) {
    Serial.println("g");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "....") == 0) {
    Serial.println("h");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "..") == 0) {
    Serial.println("i");
  }
   else if (strcmp(m, ".---") == 0) {
    Serial.println("j");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "-.-") == 0) {
    Serial.println("k");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, ".-..") == 0) {
    Serial.println("l");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, "--") == 0) {
    Serial.println("m");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, "-.") == 0) {
    Serial.println("n");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, "---") == 0) {
    Serial.println("o");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, ".--.") == 0) {
    Serial.println("p");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, "--.-") == 0) {
    Serial.println("q");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, ".-.") == 0) {
    Serial.println("r");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, "...") == 0) {
    Serial.println("s");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "-") == 0) {
    Serial.println("t");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "..-") == 0) {
    Serial.println("u");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "...-") == 0) {
    Serial.println("v");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, ".--") == 0) {
    Serial.println("w");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "-..-") == 0) {
    Serial.println("x");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "-.--") == 0) {
    Serial.println("y");
  }
  else if (strcmp(m, "--..") == 0) {
    Serial.println("z");
  }
 else if (strcmp(m, "/") == 0) {
  Serial.println(" ");
}
}
char * charstring2morsestring(char * ip, char * buf, int buflen){
  char backslash = '/';
  char * currentchar;
  int i;
  char  morsecat[buflen];
  //morsecat[0] = '\0';
  char * temp;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(ip);i++){


    do {

    *temp = ip;
    strcat(morsecat, temp);
    //Serial.println(morsecat);


    } while (ip != '/');

    if (ip == '/') {
    *currentchar = morse2char(morsecat);
    strcat(buf, currentchar);
    morsecat[buflen] = ' ';
    }





      }


Serial.println(buf);   
  }










void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Serial.println(morse2char(".-"));
  //Serial.println(morse2char("-..."));
  //Serial.println(morse2char("--.."));
  charstring2morsestring(".-/-.../--../.", buf, 50);

}


void loop(){


}
```

Comment: I don´t fully understand your problem explanation, but some array and a loop would make your if chain shorter.

Comment: You should consider an algorithm that is a tree based on each "dot" or "dash" to decode (don't forget that a . is the first of ..-).

Comment: Consider this tree http://www.learnmorsecode.com/

Comment: The way you break up the morse string is easier to accomplish using strtok() in a loop. You don't need to pass in the buf or buflen, either.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a `c` code. However, from the logical angle, first you should

1. `*temp = ip;` is wrong, maybe what you want is`temp = ip;`
2. `(ip != '/');` you cannot use `==` for string comaprison. use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).
3. `*currentchar = morse2char(morsecat);` but I cannot spot `morse2char()` returning anyting.

and there are many more logical problem in your code, like ineffective `do..while` loop and all.